# Why doesn't KDevel find the class definitions?

Tags: kubuntu, kdevelop

I am trying (for the second time) Kubuntu on a Hyper-V virtual machine, but in  both the cases I am getting the following behavior from KDevel.

I installed KDevel using Discover, I opened KDevel, and tried creating an application using one of the templates it gives (*Qt* > *Graphical* > *KParts Application*).

The code I get in main.cpp is the following one.

```
#include "kdrupalconsoleshell.h"

// KF headers
#include <KAboutData>
#include <KLocalizedString>

// Qt headers
#include <QApplication>
#include <QCommandLineParser>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QDir>
#include <QIcon>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    KLocalizedString::setApplicationDomain("kdrupalconsole");

    KAboutData aboutData(QStringLiteral("kdrupalconsole"),
        i18n("KDrupalConsole"),
        QStringLiteral("%{VERSION}"),
        i18n("A KPart Application"),
        KAboutLicense::GPL,
        i18n("Copyright %{CURRENT_YEAR} %{AUTHOR}"));
    aboutData.addAuthor(i18n("%{AUTHOR}"), i18n("Author"), QStringLiteral("%{EMAIL}"));
    aboutData.setOrganizationDomain("example.org");
    aboutData.setDesktopFileName(QStringLiteral("org.example.kdrupalconsole"));

    KAboutData::setApplicationData(aboutData);
    app.setWindowIcon(QIcon::fromTheme(QStringLiteral("kdrupalconsole")));

    QCommandLineParser parser;
    parser.addHelpOption();
    parser.addVersionOption();
    aboutData.setupCommandLine(&parser);
    parser.addPositionalArgument(QStringLiteral("urls"), i18n("Document(s) to load."), QStringLiteral("[urls...]"));

    parser.process(app);
    aboutData.processCommandLine(&parser);

    const auto urls = parser.positionalArguments();

    if (urls.isEmpty()) {
        auto window = new KDrupalConsoleShell;
        window->show();
    } else {
        for (const auto &url : urls) {
            auto window = new KDrupalConsoleShell;
            window->show();
            window->loadDocument(QUrl::fromUserInput(url, QDir::currentPath(), QUrl::AssumeLocalFile));
        }
    }

    return app.exec();
}
```

When I look at what reported in the *Problems* tab, I get the following errors, from the semantic analysis. (I report just part of them.)

> 'QCommandLineParser' file not found
>   'QUrl' file not found
>   'QDir' file not found
>   'QIcon' file not found
>   Unknown type name 'QApplication'
>   Use of undeclared identifier 'KLocalizedString'
>   Unknown type name 'KAboutData'
>   Use of undeclared identifier 'QStringLiteral'
>   Use of undeclared identifier 'i18n'
>   Use of undeclared identifier 'QStringLiteral'
>   Use of undeclared identifier 'i18n'
>   Use of undeclared identifier 'KAboutLicense'

If I click with the right button on *Unknown type name 'QApplication'*, I get a fix hint that suggest to include a new header file. After I apply some of the fix-it hints, the list of the included header files changes to the following one.

```
#include "kdrupalconsoleshell.h"
#include <qt5/QtWidgets/qapplication.h>
#include <KF5/KI18n/klocalizedstring.h>
#include <KF5/KCoreAddons/kaboutdata.h>
#include <qt5/QtWidgets/qapplication.h>

// KF headers
#include <KAboutData>
#include <KLocalizedString>

// Qt headers
#include <QApplication>
#include <QCommandLineParser>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QDir>
#include <QIcon>
```

Now, I get new errors, like *Variable has incomplete type 'QApplication'* for which the fix-it hint is adding the already present `#include <qt5/QtWidgets/qapplication.h>` line.

Apart from applying the fix-it hints I reported, I didn't edit the code generated from the IDE.

Is there anything I need to do before starting to create code? Do I need, for example, to change settings, tell KDevel to perform some actions, or install something more?

If this makes any difference, I am using KDevel 5.2.1.